# App Crashing when requesting Location Permission from Users on Runtime in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, request, location, android-permissions

When I move to another tab i just requesting runtime permission for location(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), that time application was crashed.

```
private void RequestPermissions()
        {
            try
            {
                bool shouldProvideRationale = Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation);

                if (shouldProvideRationale)
                {
                    Log.Info(Tag, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Activity, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 1);
                    Log.Info(Tag, "Requesting permission");
                    // StartLocationPermissionRequest();
                }
            }
}
```

I need the popup will stay till i response to that permission.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare permission in the Manifest?
If not, go to AndroidManifest.xml and add: < 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Yes i declared this permission in manifest, but still app crashed

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution for the exact same thing which is something as follows:

In your OnCreate method check for existing permissions:

```
 if (!(CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) &&
            CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)))
        {
            RequestLocationPermission();
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeLocationManager();
        }
        InitPageWidgets();
```

Where Check permission Granted is a method something like this:

```
 [Export]
    public bool CheckPermissionGranted(string Permissions)
    {
        // Check if the permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Permissions) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

And the Request permission code looks something like this:

```
  private void RequestLocationPermission()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation))
        {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PermissionsLocation, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }
        else
        {
            // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PermissionsLocation, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

Once you accept or reject this permission this method will get called:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions,
                     Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == RequestPermissionsRequestCode)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length <= 0)
            {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.Info(Tag, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            }
            else if (grantResults[0] == PermissionChecker.PermissionGranted)
            {
                // Permission was granted.
                Service.RequestLocationUpdates();
            }
            else
            {
                // Permission denied.
                SetButtonsState(false);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Permission Denied", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```